# Polynomial in Hilbert space definition

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, polynomials, hilbert-spaces

I ve been looking around but haven't really found anything. How does one define polynomials in a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. So a function $F:\mathcal{H}\rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ such that $F$ is a "polynomial" - the definition should of course be the same for $\mathcal{H} = \mathbb{R}^p$. Is there any obvious definition for this ?? Do we also need have a notion of multiplication on said Hilbertspace so that one could for example define $x,x^2,...$ with $x \in \mathcal{H}$.

Edit: I just realized one way to maybe get around a multiplication operation is to define a polynomial of degree 2 for example as an operator, for fixed $(g,h,f)$, as
$ x \mapsto <x<x,g>,h>f$.

Edit: I found an answer: For a Banach space one usually defines a polynomial as a multilinear map $T:B\rightarrow B' $, where $B,B'$ are two Banach space of the form $x \mapsto T(x,....,x)$ - which is also invariant under permutations. In a Hilbert space this can for example using a orthonormal basis $e_i$ boil down for second degree polynomials to $T(x,x)=\sum_{i,j} <x,e_i><x,e_j>h_{i,j} $. So the terms $<x,e_i><x,e_j>h_{i,j}$ could be interpreted as monomials. Which coincides with my first edit/suspicion.

Comment: I would say to look into linear, bilinear, trilinear, ... forms

Comment: but these map from the hilbert space to the complex/real space. Already good but not quite what I m looking for :/

Comment: I hadn't noticed that you were looking for $\mathcal{H}$-valued maps. I would say that the same should work replacing "forms" with "applications" (and taking sums of them). I never looked into them btw, so I'm not quite sure about which kind of (nice) property we could expect from them. Hopefully someone would expand, maybe pointing to useful references.

Comment: Sorry, nonsense, we need a product structure on $\mathcal{H}$ to make this sensible... maybe it should have an algebra structure, not quite sure.

Comment: So we are looking for a generalization of Banach algebras but in the special case that the Banach space comes with an inner product?

Comment: not quite sure what you mean, in the L2 space of square integrable functions we could have pointwise multiplication so there it shouldn  t be a problem (however we need to make sure that powers are again in L2 so some assumptions would have to be made). I edited my question above and added an idea about how this might be done. any thoughts ?

Comment: What do you understand by an $\mathbb{R}^{n}$-valued polynomial?

Comment: Well, for every coordinate we have all monomial products, e.g $x_{1}^{d_1}*...x_{n}^{d_n}$